# android attribute in a style being ignored

Tags: android, android-styles, android-gridlayout

I created a button style for a grid of buttons, but for some weird reason one of the attributes of the style does not work. It is weird because everything else does. Can someone spot the issue?

here is my button:

```
    <Button
        style="@style/BtnStyle"
            grid:layout_columnWeight="1"
        android:text="7" />
```

and here it its style:

```
<style name="BtnStyle">
    <item name="android:layout_width">@dimen/btn_width</item>
    <item name="android:layout_height">@dimen/btn_height</item>
    <item name="android:textSize">@dimen/btn_text_size</item>
    <item name="android:background">@drawable/btn_shape</item>
    <item name="android:textColor">#ffffff</item>
    <item name="grid:layout_columnWeight">1</item>
    <item name="grid:layout_gravity">fill_horizontal</item>
    <item name="android:gravity">center</item>
</style>
```

all attributes are being propagated, but the "grid:layout_columnWeight" is being ignored. So I have to repeat it multiple times.

thank you!

Comment: Did you insert your button into `GridLayout`?

Comment: yes, there is a grid layout with it.

Answer (score 0):

I don't grid:layout_columnWeight is an valid android attribute since its prefix is **grid** but not **android**. If you're using GridLayout, you may need to use **android:layout_columnWeight**
 (https://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/GridLayout.LayoutParams.html)

If it's an attribute from library, you may need to add something like

```
xmlns:appcompat="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
```

in the xml's root tag.

If it's for custom library, I think you should define the attribute in res/attr/